# Problem with parsing JSON response and deserializing

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

On recieving a response from the external system, I used Json2Apex to create the apex class viz., **AuthCalloutPostWrapper**

When I use the following debug

```
 System.debug('##res.getBody##'+res.getBody());
```

I get a proper JSON response.

> requestbody##{
>     "short_description" : "test",
>     "caller_id" : "00001xx3",
>     "priority" : "High",
>   }

But when I used this...

```
 String responseBody = res.getBody();
 AuthCalloutPostWrapper JSONDetails=(AuthCalloutPostWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(responseBody, AuthCalloutPostWrapper.class);
 System.debug('##JSONDetails##'+JSONDetails);
```

JSONDetails return me null in all the parameters.

> JSONDetails##AuthCalloutPostWrapper:[caller_id=null, priority=null, short_description=null]

UPDATE: Also using..

```
  AuthCalloutPostWrapper  myJSON = AuthCalloutPostWrapper.parse(responseBody);
```

returns me null in all the parameters.

UPDATE: For the code below:

```
 HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
 System.debug('##res.getBody##'+res.getBody());
```

Here's the full response:

> res.getBody##{"result":{"location":"","expected_start":"","reopen_count":"0","close_notes":"","impact":"1","urgency":"1","sys_domain":{"link":"xxx/table/sys/global","value":"global"},"description":"","group_list":"","priority":"1","delivery_plan":"","sys_mod_count":"0","work_notes_list":"","follow_up":"","closed_at":"","sla_due":"","delivery_task":"","sys_updated_on":"2015-12-17 01:49:04","parent":"","work_end":"","number":"xxx123","closed_by":"","work_start":"","calendar_stc":"","business_duration":"","category":"inquiry","incident_state":"1","activity_due":"","correlation_display":"","company":"","active":"true","due_date":"","assignment_group":"","caller_id":{"link":abc/api/now/table/sys_user/ababd","value":"ababd"},"knowledge":"false","made_sla":"true","comments_and_work_notes":"","parent_incident":"","state":"1","user_input":"","approval_set":"","reassignment_count":"0","rfc":"","u_record_url":"","child_incidents":"0","opened_at":"2015-12-17 07:49:04","short_description":"test as subject","order":"","sys_updated_by":"admin","resolved_by":"","notify":"1","upon_reject":"cancel","approval_history":"","problem_id":"","work_notes":"","calendar_duration":"","close_code":"","sys_id":"xxxx","approval":"not requested","caused_by":"","severity":"3","sys_created_by":"User1","resolved_at":"","assigned_to":"","bus_abc":"","sys_domain_path":"/","cmdb_ci":"","opened_by":{"link":"xxx/api/now/table/sys_user/abc","value":"abadw"},"subcategory":"","sys_class_name":"incident","watch_list":"","time_worked":"","contact_type":"phone","escalation":"0","comments":"test"}}

Let me know where I might have gone wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper class should be as follows

```
public class AuthCalloutPostWrapper{
    public String short_description;    //test
    public String caller_id;    //xxxx
    public String priority; //High
    public static AuthCalloutPostWrapper parse(String json){
        return (AuthCalloutPostWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, AuthCalloutPostWrapper.class);
    }

}
```

and you can call this in following way

```
String responseBody = res.getBody();
 AuthCalloutPostWrapper JSONDetails=AuthCalloutPostWrapper.parse(responseBody);
 System.debug('##JSONDetails##'+JSONDetails);
```

Comment: Hello once again! Ditto but doesn't seem to work!

Comment: I have tested this and it is working fine. It seems like you have problem with your json. I can see two times caller_id, remove last one.  json should be like this { "short_description" : "test","priority" : "High", "caller_id" : "xxxx" }

Comment: got the issue ?

Comment: Hey I corrected and I have only 1 caller_id now. But still I get null values. Let me post the JSON response as update in my question